# Group By returning 1st column values twice

Tags: sql

I have data that looks like:

```
ACC311  Female  3
ACC311  Female  1
ACC311  Female  4
ACC311  Male    4
ACC501  Male    4
ACC501  Male    4
ACC501  Male    4
ACC501  Male    4
.
.
.
```

Now I am using following query to get results

```
Select distinct coursecode, gender, Count(CQ) as CQ from Table1
group by Coursecode, gender
order by Coursecode
```

It is returning results as following, which is obviously not a correct
way as per required output (see below)

```
CourseCode Gender   CQ

ACC311     Male     45

ACC311     Female   22

ACC501     Female   228

ACC501     Male     485
```

Where as I need to get following:

```
CourseCode  Total   Male    Female  CQ

ACC311      67      45      22      11

ACC501      713     485     228     111
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns rows "twice" because you group by `Coursecode, gender`. `DISTINCT` won't help either.

The easiest way to get desired result is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Coursecode,
       Count(CQ) AS CQ,
       COUNT(gender) AS Total,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN gender = 'Male' THEN 1 END) AS Male,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS Female
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Coursecode
```